# WSO2 Data services feature in ESB 4.0.3 puts wrong default value in returned XML

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 4.0.3 on MAC OS X 10.7.4 with Java 6.0

I have Data Services Feature installed in the ESB. Typical problem is for the output values for the XML elements where the DB column type is integer and value is null in DB. WSO2 Data service puts the default value of 0 when DB value for integer data type is null.

e.g. if I have table with column named "Customer Number" of type Integer and with value null in DB then the returned XML element from Data Service is 0<\CUSTOMER_NUMBER>. I am expecting empty element being returned if the DB value is null for that column.

Can you please let me know if there is any configuration for Data Services type which I can set?

Answer (score 0):

There is no external configuration for that. This actually had been an issue and fixed to set the default value of that type if null is present in the DB.For int '0' is assigned by default.

this is the reported [JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-13024)